# How to pass * to a java program without wildcard expansion?

Tags: java, bash, cygwin, glob

Consider following simple Java program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(args));
    }
}
```

Glob expansion is typically done by shell, not by JVM. Example, in Cygwin:

```
$ echo *
Main.class
```

Here Cygwin expanded `*` to Main.class (file in the directory)

This behavior can be turned off:

```
$ set -f
$ echo *
*
```

Now `*` has not been expanded.

However when passing `*` to the Java program the wildcard somehow gets expanded:

```
$ set -f
$ java Main *
[Main.class]
```

Quoting or escaping doesn't help either:

```
$ java Main '*'
[Main.class]
$ java Main \*
[Main.class]
```

Who's the culprit here, Shell or Java? It seems JVM, because a python program works fine:

Python file `a.py`:

```
import sys
print  sys.argv[1:]
```

Run python program with wildcard:

```
$ set -f; python a.py *
['*']
```

No expansion.

**Why is JVM expanding the wildcard? That is supposed to be a function of Shell, not JVM. How can this be turned off?**

Comment: Unclear what you are asking: which of these behaviors do you actually want? Or, if not above, what do you want it to do?

Comment: What is the problem here? Or you just after some documentation about it? There are few articles about it on `*.java.net`

Comment: @Andy Changed the title to better reflect intention. JVM should leave the arguments as is. Infact there are a lot of questions here on SO asking how to have JVM expand globs. And the answer is it can't. That's a feature of the shell not JVM.

Comment: Wouldn't escape work??Such as:  java Main \*

Comment: @oldercoder Escape? You mean `java Main \*`? No it doesn't

Comment: On Unix, this is up to the shell. On Windows, this is up to the program. Since you're running a Windows program from a Unix shell, I imagine you get two passes.

Comment: @thatotherguy The first pass (cygwin) has been disabled with `set -f` as demonstrated with examples. A second pass shouldn't exist. As you've just said *this is up to the program*. JVM doesn't do glob expansions. You'll have to do something like `Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.txt")` for that. But assuming JVM does do expansion for main method arguments, how would one disable it?

Comment: Besides, Python is also a windows program (.exe)

Comment: I stumbled into this behavior at https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/1761. This is complete news to me. So you're saying the OpenJDK `java -jar` command is expanding argument wildcards on Windows? Is this documented somewhere? Is this a requirement of the JDK? Does the Sun implementation do this as well, or is it only OpenJDK behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix, glob expansion is handled by the shell, and not by the program.

On Windows, glob expansion is handled by the program, and not by the shell.

This means that when you run a Windows program from a Unix shell, you risk having two passes of glob expansion.

Here's the [Windows OpenJDK source code](https://github.com/dmlloyd/openjdk/blob/342a565a2da8abd69c4ab85e285bb5f03b48b2c9/src/java.base/windows/native/libjli/java_md.c#L1006-L1019) responsible for this:

```
/*
 * At this point we have the arguments to the application, and we need to
 * check with original stdargs in order to compare which of these truly
 * needs expansion. cmdtoargs will specify this if it finds a bare
 * (unquoted) argument containing a glob character(s) ie. * or ?
 */
jobjectArray
CreateApplicationArgs(JNIEnv *env, char **strv, int argc)
{
   // (***snip***)
    NULL_CHECK0(mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls,
                                                "expandArgs",
                                                "([Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;"));

    // expand the arguments that require expansion, the java method will strip
    // out the indicator character.
    NULL_CHECK0(inArray = NewPlatformStringArray(env, nargv, argc));
    outArray = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, cls, mid, inArray);
```

And here's is the [expandArgs](https://github.com/dmlloyd/openjdk/blob/d04c93b468710dd335daee66f2f4abca91bc77a6/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/launcher/LauncherHelper.java#L771) that it calls into:

```
static String[] expandArgs(List<StdArg> argList) {
    ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<>();
      // (***snip***)
            try (DirectoryStream<Path> dstream =
                    Files.newDirectoryStream(parent.toPath(), glob)) {
                int entries = 0;
                for (Path p : dstream) {
                    out.add(p.normalize().toString());
                    entries++;
                }
```

I don't know if this behavior can be disabled. Consider passing data in files, or use Windows Subsystem for Linux which simulates a Unix environment more accurately than CygWin.